# getting error whne using client.get_bucket_policy_status from S3 backet

Tags: amazon-s3, botocore

I try to get the policy status of S3 bucket using the following script

```
import boto3

regionNameArg = 'us-east-1'
awsAccessKeyId = 'XXX'
awsSecretAccessKey = 'XXX'

# Create an S3 client
client = boto3.client(service_name='s3',
                      region_name=regionNameArg,
                      aws_access_key_id=awsAccessKeyId,
                      aws_secret_access_key=awsSecretAccessKey)

# Call S3 to list current buckets
response = client.list_buckets()
print(response)

# Get a list of all bucket names from the response
buckets = [bucket['Name'] for bucket in response['Buckets']]
for S3Bucket in buckets:
    publicstatus1=client.get_public_access_block(Bucket='S3Bucket')
    print(publicstatus1)
    publicstatus = client.get_bucket_policy_status(Bucket='S3Bucket')
    print (publicstatus)
```

I add the full permissions to the user on this S3 bucket but still getting an error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the GetPublicAccessBlock operation: All access to this object has been disabled
```

any idea what can be the cause? any solution suggested?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the S3Bucket is taken as a String since its given under quotes